# Use Twilio for app to app VoIP calls

Tags: android, twilio

We are developing an Android app with VoIP call feature like WhatsApp's calls.

Following quick-start guides and examples provided by Twilio in their web we managed to make a simple VoIP app for testing ([Android Client Tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client)), but when we configured server side app (provided in their examples) we were asked to enter a callerID that must be a valid phone number.

Why is this callerId needed and why it has to be a valid number phone if we just want to make app to app VoIP calls, without using any real mobile number?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50409940/2437655

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Using [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client) you can make both app to app calls and app to phone calls. You only need a calledId if you are calling out to the phone network. You can get a free phone number with your Twilio trial account and use that if you want to follow the [Android Client Tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client) exactly.

Otherwise, you can skip the bits of the app where you call phones and just send calls out to other Clients. When you do that, you need only to set the callerId as your Client name.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: so **callerId** would be valid for SIP calls? I've already twilio working, but now I want setup [ConnectionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService.html) to use the Android UI Phone and avoid create an UI dial screen. But while the VOIP it's on I can't keep the UI opened.

Comment: `callerId` would be valid for SIP calls yes. I'm afraid I'm not an Android developer, so can't really advise on using `ConnectionService`. I do hope it works well for you though. If you come across specific issues, then please do open another SO question and hopefully someone with more experience will be able to help you there.